# Remove the time series before sequence of zero using sql

Tags: sql, subquery, window-functions, amazon-athena

I have a time series as follows :

```
Day.          Data 

1/1/2020.     0
2/1/2020      .2
3/1/2020      0
......       ...
1/2/2020      0
2/2/2020.     0
3/2/2020.     .2
4/2/2020.     .3
5/2/2020.     0
6/2/2020      0
7/2/2020.     0
8/2/2020      2
9/2/2020      2.4
10/2/2020     3
```

So I want filter data only show after final sequence of zeros that we have in time series in this case I want to get only data after 8/2/202.
I have tried this

```
SELECT * FROM table where Data> 0
```

here is the result :

```
Day.          Data 
    
    2/1/2020      .2
    ......       ...
    3/2/2020.     .2
    4/2/2020.     .3
    8/2/2020      2
    9/2/2020      2.4
    10/2/2020     3
```

However this does not find the lates 0 and remove everything before that.

I want also show the result 2 days after the final zero in sequence in the table.

```
Day           Data
10/2/2020     3
11/2/2020.    3.5
.....        ....
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: I am running it in athena I think is it postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.day > (select max(t2.day) from t t2 where t2.value = 0);
```

You can offset this:

```
where t.day > (select max(t2.day) + interval '2' day from t t2 where t2.value = 0);
```

The above assumes that at least one row has zeros. Here are two easy fixes:

```
where t.day > all (select max(t2.day) from t t2 where t2.value = 0);
```

or:

```
where t.day > (select coalesce(max(t2.day), '2000-01-01') from t t2 where t2.value = 0);
```

Comment: when you mention max(t2.day) does it mean that it will check the Data column to find max values?

Comment: @user . . . The subquery finds the maximum value of `day` where the value is `0`.

Comment: does it consider the sequence as well?

Comment: @user . . . I don't understand the comment.  It picks up all rows after the last one with `value = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select day, data
from (
    select t.*, max(case when data = 0 then day end) over() day0
    from mytable t
) t
where day > day0 or day0 is null
order by day0
```

This is easily adapted if you want to start two days after the last `0`:

```
select day, data
from (
    select t.*, max(case when data = 0 then day end) over() day0
    from mytable t
) t
where day > day0 + interval '2 day' or day0 is null
order by day0
```

Comment: When I run the code it tells me "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() day0" . because my day column is acutlay lables as date not day could you please let me know how i can fix it. shall I change day0 into date0. over() is in oracle i am using mysql and postgresql so because of this it is not working.

Comment: Also when I use it in athena using prstgresql it tells that Query exhausted resources at this scale factor

Comment: the other problem is in the  interval '2 day' , day should comes out of single qout interval '2' day